# How to pass sharedpreferences value with url?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Hi i want to pass sharedpreferences value (ex:user id saved in shared pref)URL in api interface android or is there any way to do that.i am new to programming

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("user.php/**{user_id}**")
    Call<UpdateUserResponse> sentUserUpdateddata(
            @Field("first_name") String first_name,
            @Field("last_name") String last_name,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("user_id") String user_id
    );
```

I dont have any idea about how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the user ID from SharedPreferences:

```
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String userId = sharedPreferences.getString("user_id", "");
```

Update your API interface to use @Path instead of @Field for the user ID:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("user.php/**{user_id}**")
Call<UpdateUserResponse> sentUserUpdateddata(
        @Field("first_name") String first_name,
        @Field("last_name") String last_name,
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password,
        @path("user_id") String user_id
);
```

When making the API call, pass the retrieved user ID as an argument:

```
    Call<UpdateUserResponse> call = yourApiService.sentUserUpdatedData(firstName, lastName, email, password, userId);
call.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateUserResponse>() {
    // Handle the response
    // ...
});
```